# How to read text line by line in a html text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, textarea

How can I read the contents of a text area line by line or split the text in different lines
to obtain input as lines of text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the Javascript [`split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 7):

Try this one....

you can split by "\n" and then get lilne by line value using for loop

```
var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
    //code here using lines[i] which will give you each line
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it  by  using `split()` method.

```
 var splittedLines= inputString.split('\n');
```

And where `splittedLines`  is an `array`.Loop through `splittedLines` to get the each line.

Answer (score 1):

`var arr = yourtext.split("\n");`

loop arr to get each line.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the value of the textarea to an array by splitting on the newline \n character